# How to pass on parameters into a custom google-sheets function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, parameter-passing, named-ranges, custom-function

I have a sheet with several custom formulas - and for these to work- they need to be updated based on the dynamically generated range from column A.

The issue is that whilst "A" column-range grows larger, my custom functions e.g. "test1(A1:A??)" need to have its range parameter updated with the new range-value of the "A" column - or these wouldn't execute.

Probably there are some g-sheets built-in functions to derive dynamic ranges from a column in such a way that these can be built into a custom formula??? thoughts?

An embarrassing shot in the dark would be something like this, I think -which obviously doesn't work.

```
=test1(INDIRECT(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COUNTA($A:$A),1)))
```

As a result, I would expect my custom function parameters to update dynamically from "test1(A1:A25)" to "test1(A1:A128)".

Comment: That should work

Comment: Unfortunately it returns an error i.e. "Range not found (line...)" ... Probably another combination with the 'address' function? But not sure how...

Comment: Remove indirect

Comment: Why are you not using "test1(A:A)" ?